# Lotus Notes ODBC Connection and SQL BLOB field

Tags: sql, vba, lotus-domino

I am working on Lotus Notes 9, I have few records in lotus notes database with attachment into documents.

Now I would like to move this document records to SQL server with all text and number fields and etc. I was wondering if somebody can help me on Attachments. How I cab attach attachment to SQL server BLOB fields type using LotusScript or JDBC ( using LS2J code )?

I know using ODBC connection some stuff can be achieved but not sure how. If somebody has performed similar exercise, any help would be highly appreciated.

Here is code, in SQL table I set field *FileNameAtt* is `varbinary(max)`.

```vb
Sub Initialize

    Dim cn As Variant
    Dim rs As Variant

    ' Variable declarations
    Dim file_length As Variant
    Dim NumBlocks As Variant
    Dim leftover As Variant
    Dim inBuff As Variant, outBuff() As Byte

    'VB Constants
    Const adOpenKeyset = 1
    Const adLockOptimistic = 3
    Const adTypeBinary = 1
    Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
    Const adBlocksize = 4096

    'Connect to the serve server
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    ' Open provider
    cn.open "SQLConnectionCSIDB", "user1", ""

    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Set stream = session.CreateStream
    Call stream.open("C:\\Image1.PNG")
    file_length=stream.Bytes

    If file_length > 0 Then
        num_blocks = Int(file_length / adBlocksize)
        left_over = file_length Mod adBlocksize

        Call rs.Open("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tblFiles", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic)

        rs.AddNew
        'rs.Fields("dsize").Value = file_length
        rs.Fields("FileNameAtt").Value ="C:\\Image1.PNG"

        ' Get blocks of the file
        ReDim outBuff(adBlocksize)
        For block_num = 1 To num_blocks
            ' Get data into a variant
            inBuff = stream.Read(adBlocksize)

            ' Move to byte array
            counter% = 0
            ForAll b In inBuff
                outBuff(counter%) = b
                counter% = counter% + 1
            End ForAll

            ' Save to field
            rs.Fields("dimage").AppendChunk(outBuff)
        Next block_num

        ' Get the remainder of the file
        If left_over > 0 Then
            inBuff = stream.Read(left_over) 

            ' Move to byte array
            counter% = 0
            ReDim outBuff(left_over)
            ForAll b In inBuff
                outBuff(counter%) = b
                counter% = counter% + 1
            End ForAll

            ' Save to field
            rs.Fields("dimage").AppendChunk(outBuff)
        End If  

        rs.Update
        Call rs.Close
    End If

    Call cn.Close
    Set stream = Nothing
    Set session = Nothing
End Sub
```

it gives error as below at line number

```vb
rs.Fields("FileNameAtt").Value ="C:\\Image1.PNG"
```

Microsoft OLEDB provider for ODBC Drivers: Multi-step OLE DB operation generated error, check each OLE DB status value if available not work done

Thanks
Man

Comment: @parfait - it looks like the question is not so much how to store BLOBs (that is easy), but how to get the binary data out of Notes

Comment: @parfait,@Normunds Kalnberzins,@Richard Schwartz I have updated code, please help if you can.

Comment: Your code works well. I have fixed some typos and used it in my agent to store binary data in the SQL Table. If you do it right, it works. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to access attachments through NotesSQL.

LotusScript can work with attachments using the [NotesEmbeddedObject class](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_NOTESEMBEDDEDOBJECT_CLASS.html) and related methods in the [NotesDocument](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_NOTESDOCUMENT_CLASS.html?view=kc), [NotesRichTextItem](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_NOTESRICHTEXTITEM_CLASS.html) and [NotesRichTextNavigator](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_NOTESRICHTEXTNAVIGATOR_CLASS.html) classes. Those same capabilities are also available through the [Lotus COM classes](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_ACCESSING_THE_DOMINO_OBJECTS_THROUGH_COM.html) for programs written in VB, C# and other languages, and equivalent [Java classes](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_JAVA_NOTES_CLASSES_JAVA.html) are also available.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed some variables in your code and was able to make it work.
Here is my working LS Agent:

```
Option Public
Option Declare

Sub Initialize
    
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase

    Dim cn As Variant
    Dim rs As Variant
    
    ' Variable declarations
    Dim file_length As Variant
    Dim num_blocks As Variant
    Dim left_over As Variant
    Dim inBuff As Variant, outBuff() As Byte

    'VB Constants
    Const adOpenKeyset = 1
    Const adLockOptimistic = 3
    Const adTypeBinary = 1
    Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
    Const adBlocksize = 4096
    
    'Connect to the serve server
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    
    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;" _  
    & "Server=(localdb)\.;" _  
    & "Database=Test;" _   
    & "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    
    '& "Trusted_Connection=yes;"   
    
    ' Open provider
    cn.open 
    Dim stream As Variant
    Set stream = session.CreateStream
    Call stream.open("c:\Temp\Image.jpg")
    file_length=stream.Bytes
        
    If file_length > 0 Then
        num_blocks = Int(file_length / adBlocksize)
        left_over = file_length Mod adBlocksize
        
        Call rs.Open("SELECT * FROM Files", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic)

        rs.AddNew
        rs.Fields("Id").Value = 1

        ' Get blocks of the file
        ReDim outBuff(adBlocksize)
        dim block_num As Integer
        Dim counter%
        For block_num = 1 To num_blocks
            ' Get data into a variant
            inBuff = stream.Read(adBlocksize)

            ' Move to byte array
            counter% = 0
            ForAll b In inBuff
                outBuff(counter%) = b
                counter% = counter% + 1
            End ForAll

            ' Save to field
            rs.Fields("Data").AppendChunk(outBuff)
        Next block_num

        ' Get the remainder of the file
        If left_over > 0 Then
            inBuff = stream.Read(left_over) 

            ' Move to byte array
            counter% = 0
            ReDim outBuff(left_over)
            ForAll b In inBuff
                outBuff(counter%) = b
                counter% = counter% + 1
            End ForAll

            ' Save to field
            rs.Fields("Data").AppendChunk(outBuff)
        End If  

        rs.Update
        Call rs.Close
    End If

    Call cn.Close
    Set stream = Nothing
    Set session = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

The table `Files` has the following structure:

```
Id: int PK
Data: varbinary(max)
```

The resulting Row:

[image]

---

Check the other answer about attachments in Lotus and search for attachment export with LotusScript. It's not so complicated.